# Access Denied when trying to run simple Java program

Tags: java

I'm very new to Java. In fact, I'm trying to run the classic Hello World program.

My problem is that when I try to run the program through Command Prompt, I always get a response of "Access is denied." I've tried moving my HelloWorld.java file to various places throughout my computer, but none of them has allowed the program to run. Originally, this was my executing command:

C:\Programs>java HelloWorld

This gave me "Access is denied". I tried moving the program to another folder located on my desktop, as such:

C:\Users\Spiralgo\Desktop>java HelloWorld

And this gave me "Access is denied." I started researching online. Someone suggested that programs cannot be run under the C: drive, possibly only for Windows 7, but while I have Windows 10, I thought I'd try to follow the advice.

I moved my file(s) (there is now HelloWorld as a .java file and HelloWorld.class, I don't know where this latter program came from or what it is) to my D: drive and tried executing through there:

D:>java HelloWorld

...And again got "Access is denied." !

Then I tried running Command Prompt as an Administrator. Still got the same error. (I have not yet tried running as Administrator within D: drive, but I feel like I shouldn't really have to use D: drive.)

The rest of the information I've found on the "Access is denied." message has been too complicated for me to understand. I really hope someone here can point me in the right direction.

Comment: Run java -version from the command prompt and post the result, please.

Comment: java version "14.0.2" 2020-07-14
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 14.0.2+12-46)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 14.0.2+12-46, mixed mode, sharing)

Comment: The drive shouldn't matter at all ..

Comment: Post the whole output from the prompt here please.

Comment: Is the .class the same one from the first attempt? Or you've run javac before java every time?

Comment: Example of Input:    C:\Users\Spiralgo\Desktop>java HelloWorld

Output:                    Access is denied.

Comment: @pablo I originally wrote HelloWorld in Notepad and gave it the .java ending. I don't know where the .class version came from, except it seems to have resulted from my trying to run the HelloWorld.java (?). I'm not sure what javac is.

Comment: javac compiles a .java file

Comment: Please include your code here, pasted into the question as text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it to work! Basically, it looks like it wasn't working because I didn't give the exact folder the file was in. Here was basically the successful code:

C:\Users\Spiralgo\Desktop\Coding>java HelloWorld

And got: Hello world!

I thought Desktop would be specific enough based on examples I'd seen elsewhere, but turns out I had to include the exact folder that the program was in. I don't know why it didn't work when I had it in the Programs folder (or D:), but I'm satisfied enough. Thanks everyone.

Answer (score 0):

Try, from C:\Users\Spiralgo\Desktop:

Put your HelloWorld.java file here.
Run `javac HelloWorld.java`, which compiles the file, creating a
HelloWorld.class file.
Run `java HelloWorld`, which runs the HelloWorld.class file.

Comment: [Is there a way I can comment here so that the line breaks remain?]

C:\Users\Spiralgo\Desktop>del HelloWorld.class
Could Not Find C:\Users\Spiralgo\Desktop\HelloWorld.class

C:\Users\Spiralgo\Desktop>javac HelloWorld.java
error: file not found: HelloWorld.java
Usage: javac <options> <source files>
use --help for a list of possible options

C:\Users\Spiralgo\Desktop>java HelloWorld
Access is denied.

Comment: Ok, I assumed you had the files there, I'll edit the answer.